# Am I adding numbers to variables correctly?

Tags: python

So, I'm trying to create a password guesser for a project at school, heres a part of the code I'm having trouble with:

```
dictfile = open('c:/ScienceFairDictionaryFolder/wordsEn.txt', 'r')
DictionaryWords = dictfile.readlines()


def Number_Finder():
    for x in DictionaryWords:
        Intadd = 0
        if x.replace("\n", " ") + str(Intadd) == Password:
            print("Congrats, you found the password!")
        else:
            while Intadd <= 10:
                 Intadd +=1
                 print(x)

Number_Finder()
```

What I'm trying to aim for is for the code to look something like this:

```
Wildcat1
Wildcat2
Wildcat3
Wildcat4
Wildcat5
Wildcat6
Wildcat7
Wildcat8
Wildcat9
Wildcat10
```

However, when I run the code, I get this instead:

```
Wildcat
Wildcat
Wildcat
Wildcat
Wildcat
Wildcat
Wildcat
Wildcat
Wildcat
Wildcat
```

I think it's a problem with how I'm trying to combine the Intadd with the variable, I'm not sure though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why would a number magically appear after `x` in the `print` statement if you don't ask for it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to concatenate the `Intadd` value to `x`.

```
def Number_Finder():
    for x in DictionaryWords:
        Intadd = 0
        if x.replace("\n", " ") + str(Intadd) == Password:
            print("Congrats, you found the password!")
        else:
            while Intadd <= 10:
                 Intadd +=1
                 print(x + str(Intadd))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dictfile = open('c:/ScienceFairDictionaryFolder/wordsEn.txt', 'r')
DictionaryWords = dictfile.readlines()


def Number_Finder():
    for x in DictionaryWords:
        Intadd = 0
        if x.replace("\n", " ") + str(Intadd) == Password:
            print("Congrats, you found the password!")
        else:
            while Intadd <= 10:
                 Intadd +=1
                 print(x.replace("\n", " ") + str(Intadd))

Number_Finder()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate take on a solution using a [cool tool from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

def number_finder():
    for word, number in product(dictionary_words, range(11)):
        test_password = ''.join((word.strip(), str(number)))
        if test_password == password:
            print('Congrats...')
            break
        else:
            print(test_password)
```